# Node write stream hanging

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, stream

This node script hangs after the last line with `records written: 442`.

This means the the `finish` event has fired, but I don't know how to end the whole script.

```
const N3 = require('n3');
const fs = require('fs');
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

const uri = 'bolt://localhost';
const user = 'neo4j';
const password = 'sms1993662';
const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password));
const session = driver.session();

let streamParser = N3.StreamParser();

let rdfStream = fs.createReadStream('/Users/simonshapiro/Documents/javascript/rdf_graphlib_js/data/sh.tll')
let number_of_rows = 0;

function DatastoreWriter () {
    let writer = new require('stream').Writable({objectMode: true});
    writer._write = (triple, encoding, done) => {
            console.log(triple);
            const mergePromise = session.run(
                `MERGE (n:Unidentified {id:"${triple.subject}"})`
            );
            mergePromise.then(() => {
                number_of_rows += 1;
                done();
            })
            .catch((e)=>{
                console.log('error', e);
                done();
            });
    }
    return writer
};
const neo4jWriter = new DatastoreWriter();
rdfStream.pipe(streamParser);
streamParser.pipe(neo4jWriter);
neo4jWriter.on('finish', ()=>{
        session.close();
        console.log('records written: ', number_of_rows);
    });
```

Comment: `process.exit(0)`. But actually you should find the data that is still available (maybe the driver connection) and close that more gracefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver), the driver should be closed, which can be done like this:

```
neo4jWriter.on('finish', ()=>{
  session.close(() => driver.close());
  console.log('records written: ', number_of_rows);
});
```